# CVXPY numerical instability

Tags: python, cvxpy

I noticed that if you add to your target something multiplied by zero it will affect the solution significantly. I found this bug when using cvxpy on my dataset which I cant upload of course. But here is an example from their official resource: https://www.cvxpy.org/examples/basic/sdp.html

```
import cvxpy as cp
import numpy as np

# Generate a random SDP.
n = 3
p = 3
np.random.seed(1)
C = np.random.randn(n, n)
A = []
b = []
for i in range(p):
    A.append(np.random.randn(n, n))
    b.append(np.random.randn())

# Define and solve the CVXPY problem.
# Create a symmetric matrix variable.
X = cp.Variable((n,n), symmetric=True)
# The operator >> denotes matrix inequality.
constraints = [X >> 0]
constraints += [
    cp.trace(A[i] @ X) == b[i] for i in range(p)]

prob = cp.Problem(cp.Minimize(cp.trace(C @ X)),
              constraints)
prob.solve()

# Print result.
print("The optimal value is", prob.value)
print("A solution X is")
print(X.value)
```

Now do the same but change

```
prob = cp.Problem(cp.Minimize(cp.trace(C @ X) + 0*cp.trace(C @ X)**9),
              constraints)
```

You will see that value of X will change.

Comment: While this would not be surprising (and calling it a bug might be harsh), this cannot be reproduced here: no problem at all! Keep in mind, that you did not chose a solver explicitly and did not show which solver is used (and how! e.g. SCS without BLAS/LAPACK -> expect problems!). For me, SCS will be picked automatically as ECOS does not like it and even being a first-order based method, SCS shows not problem at all. Also: what about the objective? A 10^-9 difference there which could lead to *very different X in general* is perfectly fine given the tolerances!. Details are important!

Comment: When you add the extra term CVXPY will pass a different problem to the solver than in the first instance: there are extra quadratic cones to model the 9th power. Now even if you assume that the solver presolves them out as redundant, it may end up with a slightly different (for example differently ordered) internal representation when the optimizer is invoked, and therefore you don't have bit-for-bit reproducibility.